# kernel config, CONFIG_CRYPTO_RSA, what is this config for?

Tags: kernel-modules, encryption

I checked:

https://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/CRYPTO_RSA.html

The help text is:

Generic implementation of the RSA public key algorithm.

Is this driver for an encryption HW device, ex: from Intel/AMD CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, `CRYPTO_RSA` provides [a generic implementation of RSA](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.16.7/source/crypto/rsa.c), *i.e.* one which isn’t hardware-specific. It works on any system the kernel works on.

Comment: I am seeing `request_module: kmod_concurrent_max` error log as edited. Can you please help?

Comment: when or who will trigger this module autoload?

Comment: If a module which needs it is loaded, it will be loaded too; see `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep` on your system for your module dependencies. My kernel has it built-in so I don’t know off-hand what other modules depend on it.